# Use XSLT to display options from XSD and default values from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

if my xml says

```
<book>
   <chapter1>b</chapter1>
   <chapter3>h</chapter3>
</book>
```

my xsd says

```
<xs:schema>

  <xs:element name="chapter1">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">                                                                                                             
      <xs:enumeration value="a"/>                                                                                                               
      <xs:enumeration value="b"/>  
  </xs:restriction>                                                                                                                             
  </xs:simpleType>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</xs:element>

  <xs:element name="chapter2">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">                                                                                                             
      <xs:enumeration value="d"/>                                                                                                               
      <xs:enumeration value="e"/>  
    </xs:restriction>                                                                                                                             
  </xs:simpleType>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="chapter3">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">                                                                                                             
    </xs:restriction>                                                                                                                             
  </xs:simpleType>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

what kind of xst should I apply in order to obtain

```
<h1>chapter1</h1>
<select>
  <option>a</option>
  <option selected>b</option>
</select>

<h1>chapter3</h1>
  <input type="text" value="h">
</select>
```

Comment: You need to tell us what rules you are applying. Why are chapter1 and chapter3 treated differently? Why is option b selected? Why does option a appear twice in the output? What is coming from the source data, what is coming from the schema, and what is hard-coded in the stylesheet?

Comment: 1) chapter1 and chapter2 can only assume these particular values, while chapter3 can assume free value. 2) typo, corrected. 3) typo, corrected. 4) xml represents default values. xsd represents possible values. xst should display defaults (from xml) and other possible options (from xsd)

Comment: There's so much information in that comment that wasn't in the original question, I think you need to start again from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the schema is as simple and well-known in advance then perhaps key based processing suffices:

```
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="chapter1 | chapter2">
    <h1>{local-name()}</h1>
    <select>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('element-ref', name(), $schema)//xs:enumeration">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </select>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="xs:enumeration">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <option><xsl:if test="$value = @value"><xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>{@value}</option>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="chapter3">
    <h1>{local-name()}</h1>
    <input type="text" value="{.}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="element-ref" match="xs:element" use="@name"/>
```

Assumes `<xsl:param name="schema" select="doc('schema.xsd')"/>`.